# Creating a steepest descent algorithm to determine a 3D affine warp

Tags: c++, image, algorithm, opencv, 3d

I want to implement the 2.5D inverse compositional image alignment. For that I need to create an steepest descent image. I followed the implementation from [Code Project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24809/Image-Alignment-Algorithms) for a 2D image alignment. But I am searching for 3D warp information and because of that also for a 3D steepest descent image.

To my project, I have a 3D model interpretation, with raycasting I am creating a rgbd-image. Now I want to search for a 3D warp, which aligns this template image with a given live image to estimate the camera position.

I have currently only the gradients in X and Y direction

```
cv::Sobel(grayImg_T, Grad_TX, CV_32F, 1, 0, 3);
cv::Sobel(grayImg_T, Grad_TY, CV_32F, 0, 1, 3);
```

And I am estimating the steepest descent as follows:

```
       float* p_sd_pixel = &p_sd[cols*j * 3 + i * 3];
       p_sd_pixel[0] = (float) (-cols*Tx + rows*Ty);
       p_sd_pixel[1] = (float) Tx;
       p_sd_pixel[2] = (float) Ty;

       for(int l = 0; l < 3; l++){
           for(int m = 0; m < 3; m++){
               float* p_h = (float*)(H.data);
               p_h[3*l+m] += p_sd_pixel[l]*p_sd_pixel[m];
           }
       }
```

Both is from the 2D inverse compositional image alignment code, I have from the website of the link I posted before. I think I need also a gradient in Z direction. But I have no idea how to create the steepest descent image for 2.5D alignment and also how to determine the affine warp. How can I tackle the math or find a better way to implement this?

Comment: I believe you'll have to go beyond copy-pasting from the code project article. It's about 2d affine matching of a 1d signal on the image grid. You have a 4d signal on a 2.5d grid to be matched with a 3d model. This is a more complex problem. Assuming you want to warp by 3d rotation, translation, and scale (9 degrees of freedom!), changing the warp makes new points visible and hide others, which can drive gradient descent crazy. As to the math, it should be straightforward to derive from the Baker and Matthews papers, but you'll need to work through the calculus.